# Decode from XYZ and encode to UTF8

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I have a string encoded in XYZ and I want to encode it in UTF8. I'm looking at Buffer, but it doesn't support anything else than ASCII, Hex, Base64 and UTF8 so I can't feed it the string that I have to convert it to a buffer.

My current code (using iconv-lite) is:

```
buffer = new Buffer(str, charset);    <------ will fail as charset is ISO-8859-1 (it could be any other charset anyways)
str = iconv.decode(buffer, charset);
str = iconv.encode(buffer, 'utf8').toString('utf8');
```

I'm trying to avoid iconv as that's a PITA for Windows. Any other pure-javascript solution will be fine for me.

Comment: _FileReader's_ [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsText%28%29) may be helpful. Not sure how supported it is in _Node.js_, though.

Comment: @PaulS. I'm not sure what you're suggesting. I'm doing this inside Node.JS and that is a link for Firefox's Web API

Comment: It's actually part of the [W3C's _File API_](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#readAsDataText)

Comment: @PaulS. I'm sorry, but I really can't see how that helps. Is that method available in Node.JS?

Answer (score 0):

This is example of encoding/decoding

```
  var str = "11afe0bc36d62793bacbe46ef809a3f8de86bfdf1fc901d664c2f740ce51947c";
  var charset = "hex";
  var buffer = new Buffer(str, charset);
  var utf8String = buffer.toString(charset);
  console.log(buffer);
  console.log(utf8String);
```

Will write :

1. line : < Buffer 11 af e0 bc 36 d6 27 93 ba cb e4 6e f8 09 a3 f8 de 86 bf df 1f c9 01 d6 64 c2 f7 40 ce 51 94 7c >

2. line : 11afe0bc36d62793bacbe46ef809a3f8de86bfdf1fc901d664c2f740ce51947c

Comment: What if I don't have a hex/binary buffer, but a string with unsupported charset by Buffer?